# Problem in running C# Google API based console application from VBA

Tags: c#, vba, google-drive-api, gdrive

I have an Excel VBA application wherein i require to access the Goggle Drive. As I could not find any direct way to run Google API based application from VBA, i googled and found following two ways to run any executable through VBA and to get the output as string:

[Shell And Wait](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ShellAndWait.aspx)

[Call A C# Console App From VBA](https://myengineeringworld.net/2020/01/call-csharp-console-app-from-vba.html)

I have tested both the methods to run a normal c# binary through VBA and both are working like a charm. Subsequently, i created Google API based console application in C#. I have posted the code and executable on github at following link:

[Google API based C# command line application](https://github.com/softsingh/GoogleApi)

When i run the gdrive.exe through windows console (cmd.exe), it is running and providing the output as desired. However, when i try to run it from VBA, i get the following error:

```
The type initializer for 'gdrive.GoogleDrive' threw an exception.
```

This is the same error which one would get if the **credential.json** was not present in the **gdrive.exe** folder.

Can anyone help me fix this issue?

Comment: Best way is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare headers in first request from VBA and c#.  Then make c# headers look exactly like VBA.

Comment: Try a Chdir in VBA to folder where the exe is located.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/chdir-statement

Comment: Does it have to be VBA? You could create an Excel add-in with C#. Or if VBA is a must, you could create an activex with C#.

Comment: @jdweng 
- The Sniffer method seems to be complicated to me.
- I have tried ChDir but still its not working.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I have a very large and complex VBA based DBMS in which i need to check the drive links, upload files, download files, rename files etc. I am not sure how to communicate with Addin through VBA I have zero experience with Addin. Although this may seem like an future option.

Comment: There are too many root causes to your issue to just guess.  Using a sniffer will eliminate the guessing.  We are still not sure if the issue is simply that the folder is wrong or something else is causing the issue.  If we see the connection being made to the server than we can eliminate the folder issue and move on to find real issue.  Right now we are just guessing.  The VBA seems to be good.  The other issue may be the environmental variables.  If you are using the Net  Process the environmental variables are not set including PATH so the start info must use full path.

Comment: @JagandeepSingh, then you might try the activex option. And BTW it is more like a problem, where do you call the exe from (working directory).

Comment: @CetinBasoz The Excel file is in **MainDir** and the gdrive.exe is in **MainDir/bin/gdrive/**

Comment: @JagandeepSingh, that itself might be a problem if  credentials file path is not a full path. Try putting them all in the same folder (better is to specify fullpath of credentials file).